# Function to capitalize the first letter of each word in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I don't know if the way I'm approaching this problem is right:

```
function capitalizer (string) {
    stringArray = string.split(' ');
    for (let i = 0; i< stringArray.length; i++) { 
        var firstLetter = stringArray[i].charAt(0);
        var firstLetterCap = firstLetter.toUpperCase();
    } 
    return stringArray.join(' ');
} 
console.log(capitalizer('cat on the mat'));
```

It just returns the original string back without capitalizing anything.

Comment: You’re not using `firstLetterCap` at all.

Comment: What changes do I make to use it then?

Answer (score 1):

You better use .map function

```
function capitalizer (str) {
  return str
    .split(' ')
    .map((word) => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
    .join(' ')
}
```

As Patrick Roberts mentioned, This code will throw an exception if the string have multiple consecutive spaces.

Using the Regex to extract words and apply the function to each word

```
function capitalize(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, (txt) => txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase());
};
```

Comment: Might want to be careful if there are multiple consecutive spaces in a string, e.g. `hello  world` would just throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your logic, you should simply to uppercase each string.

```
function capitalizer (string) {
    stringArray = string.split(' ');
    for (let i = 0; i< stringArray.length; i++) { 
        stringArray[i] = stringArray[i].toUpperCase();
    } 
    return stringArray.join(' ');
} 
console.log(capitalizer('cat on the mat'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the original code you have to make sure that the firstLetterCap is used and replaced with each of the first letters.

```js
    function capitalizer (string) {
    stringArray = string.split(' ');
    for (let i = 0; i< stringArray.length; i++) { 
        var firstLetter = stringArray[i].charAt(0);
        var firstLetterCap = firstLetter.toUpperCase();
        stringArray[i] = firstLetterCap + stringArray[i].slice(1);//cap + everything else
    } 
    return stringArray.join(' ');
    } 
    console.log(capitalizer('cat on the mat'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions too:

- Capitalize any lowercase letter that is preceded by a space or the start of a line ... basically a positive lookbehind.

```js
function capitalizer (string) {
    return string
    .replace(/(?<=^|\s)[a-z]/g, s => s.toUpperCase())
} 
console.log(capitalizer('cat on the mat'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const capitalizer = s => s.replace(/\b[a-z]/g, c => c.toUpperCase())

console.log(capitalizer('cat on the mat'))
```